# Javascript : Chrome gives [object text] for [object HtmlDivElement]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, html

I'm using following for loop in one my javascript functions to create a data row in my application.

```
for (var j = 0, length = contentsArray.length; j < length; j++) {
      //get the control for the node at this index
      contentControl = contentControlDef.getControlForObjectAtContainerIndex(contentsArray[j], j);
      //repopulate node; call overwriteDomNode(instanceDom, contentsArray, index);
          contentControl.overwriteDomNode(contentsDom.childNodes[j], contentsArray, j);
    }
```

In this case, `contentsDom.childNodes` is an array of `[object HtmlDivElements]` in both IE and FF. But in Chrome, that's different. It has the same amount of elements in the array. But it has both `[object text]` and `[object HtmlDivElement]` one after another. It should have all the HtmlDivElements. Does anyone know why is this happening in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
for (var j = 0, length = contentsArray.length; j < length; j++) {
  //get the control for the node at this index
  contentControl = contentControlDef.getControlForObjectAtContainerIndex(contentsArray[j], j);
  //repopulate node; call overwriteDomNode(instanceDom, contentsArray, index);
  contentControl.overwriteDomNode(contentsDom.children[j], contentsArray, j);
}
```

`childNodes` returns also the text nodes. Use `children` if you don't need the text nodes.